# is the vite chunk split will fire bug

Tags: typescript, vite

Recently I am tried to split the frontend project dependencies(using vite as the build tool) to small pieces(<500KB) to improve the performance, but sometimes seems the split will fire the bug. for exmaple, the package load sequence will effect the application. it makes the chunk split hard and unstable, because it is hard to know all the package dependencies and hard to know the split is 100% not effect the application.

does the frontend package dependencies split dangerous? we need be very careful about the package split? It is hard to make sure all packages feature and make sure the split won't make some new issue. To my original understood, the package split just download large js by piece, any split composite would be allowed and never fired other issue.